# Python - Graphviz - Remove legend on nodes of DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a decision tree classifier from sklearn and I use pydotplus to show it.
However I don't really like when there is a lot of informations on each nodes for my presentation (entropy, samples and value).

[image]

To explain it easier to people I would like to only keep the decision and the class on it.
Where can I modify the code to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accoring to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html), it is not possible to abstain from setting the additional information inside boxes. The only thing that you may implicitly omit is the `impurity` parameter.

However, I have done it the other explicit way which is somewhat crooked. First, I save the **.dot** file setting the impurity to *False*. Then, I open it up and convert it to a string format. I use regex to subtract the redundant labels and resave it.

The code goes like this:

```
import pydotplus  # pydot library: install it via pip install pydot
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data = load_iris()
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(data.data, data.target)

export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot', impurity=False, class_names=True)

PATH = '/path/to/dotfile/tree.dot'
f = pydot.graph_from_dot_file(PATH).to_string()
f = re.sub('(\\\\nsamples = [0-9]+)(\\\\nvalue = \[[0-9]+, [0-9]+, [0-9]+\])', '', f)
f = re.sub('(samples = [0-9]+)(\\\\nvalue = \[[0-9]+, [0-9]+, [0-9]+\])\\\\n', '', f)

with open('tree_modified.dot', 'w') as file:
    file.write(f)
```

Here are the images before and after modification:

[image][image]

In your case, there seems to be more parameters in boxes, so you may want to tweak the code a little bit.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for helping ! you save me :)

Comment: How to read the modified dot file in again to be able to display the tree as normal within the python code?

Comment: Alpeter, I don't think that's possible. The .dot is just a visualization of a model. If you want to load a tree model again, you have to save it first with 'pickle' library.