# How to remove value in Decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I want to know if their is a way to remove value in DecisionTreeClassifier when you plot the tree

I've looked on all parameters but I didn't find any solutions.

```
graph = Source(export_graphviz(model,class_names = Y_feature,feature_names=X_feature,max_depth=3,proportion=True,filled=True,rounded=True,impurity=False))
graph.format = 'png'
graph.render('dtree_render',view=True)
```

Here I have a tree but the values are annoying to make the tree clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pruning Decision Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428469/pruning-decision-trees)

Comment: May be a bit after the fact. This is the closed I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821349/python-graphviz-remove-legend-on-nodes-of-decisiontreeclassifier